# HTML - find all the sub-tags in a given tag

Tags: html, go

Assume I have a html page that contains something like

```
<ul class ="good">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>

<ul class ="bad">
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
</ul>
```

I want to grab the `<li>` elements inside the first `<ul>`. From [here](https://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.net/html) I have basically copied (note: edited code per @twotwotwo comment)

```
page, _ := html.Parse(httpBody)
    var f func(*html.Node)
    f = func(n *html.Node) {
        //fmt.Println("Inside f")
        if n.Type == html.ElementNode && n.Data == "ul" {
            fmt.Println("ul found ->  ",n)
            for c := n.FirstChild; c != nil; c = c.NextSibling {
                f(c)
            }
        } else {
          fmt.Println(n.Data ,"is not the correct one")
          for c := n.FirstChild; c != nil; c = c.NextSibling { f(c) }
          }
    }
f(page)
```

But the only output I obtain is

```
 is not the correct one
html is not the correct one
head is not the correct one
body is not the correct one
```

I wonder why the recursion stops at body. I have tried with [motherfuckingwebsite.com](http://www.motherfuckingwebsite.com) which has tags inside the body

P.S. 
I have also tried

```
page := html.NewTokenizer(httpBody)

for {
    tokenType := page.Next()
    if tokenType == html.ErrorToken {
        return links
    }
    token := page.Token()
```

but this seem to show all the tokens, without caring about the tree structure.

**EDIT:**

Comment: Don't know, but you may need to write a recursive search. I think it's only searching children of the node you start at, not children of the children, etc.

Comment: It appears even a simple piece of markup like the one you've provided is wrapped in standards-compliant markup. It includes a `<html>` node and `<head>` node from what I gather. So, as per @twotwotwo's comment, you're going to have to get quite recursive to find what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have, in the past, used this package: https://github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery

It provides a "jQuery-like" interface/querying across HTML documents. With that library, its as simple as this:

```
import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery"
)

var httpBody string = `
    <ul class ="good">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
    </ul>

    <ul class ="bad">
        <li>a</li>
        <li>b</li>
        <li>c</li>
    </ul>
`

func main() {
    b := bytes.NewBufferString(httpBody)
    doc, err := goquery.NewDocumentFromReader(b)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    doc.Find("ul.good").Each(func(i int, ul *goquery.Selection) {
        ul.Find("li").Each(func(i int, li *goquery.Selection) {
            fmt.Println(li.Text())
        })
    })
}
```

Which prints:

```
1
2
3
```